# Нециклическое переключение раскладки клавиатуры в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

Установил Lubuntu 16.04
Уже много в чем разобрался.
Но я в Windows 7 и старше выставляю переключение раскладки клавиатуры так:

- Английский <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- Украинский <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
- Русский <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

На самом деле, это самый удобный способ переключения раскладки клавиатуры. 
Рука сама привыкла. И мне очень тяжело вновь возвращаться на <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> или <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.
Получается, что у меня два кирриличных языка, и потому это все тяжело и не удобно.
Как в моем Lubuntu 16.04 установить так же само?

Answer (score 2):

Заходим в "Параметры" -> "Ввод текста" -> выбираем нужную нам раскладку и в поле ***переключатся на следующий источник с помощью*** нажимаем сочетание клавиш

вот так выглядит: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это же про циклическое **пере**ключение раскладок. а вопрос был про **в**ключение конкретной раскладки.

Comment: Во-первых, у меня Lubuntu, а во-вторых мне нужно на каждый язык свое сочетание клавиш.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала выполните в консоли

```
setxkbmap -query
```

и получите где то так

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ua,ru
variant:    ,winkeys,
options:    grp:caps_toggle
```

здесь видно, что есть три раскладки и украинская раскладка требует winkeys. Поэтому, переключение на украинскую раскладку будет такое

```
setxkbmap -layout ua -variant winkeys -option grp:caps_toggle
```

а назад на английскую - такое

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option grp:caps_toggle
```

(у Вас вполне могут быть другие значения и параметры, поэтому внимательно смотрите).

Теперь, когда три команды готово и они рабочие, приступаем к второму этапу. Команды можно завернуть в скрипты и добавить к примеру notify-send для красоты и метрики:)

В настройках клавиатуры есть Application Shortcut. Там можно добавить свои shortcut. Добавляете, а команды для них уже знаете. Сами выбираете, как какой кнопке какой язык привязать.

Этот способ имеет один недостаток - он ломает стандартную переключалку. Поэтому, команды нужно чуточку по другому задавать - украинский

```
setxkbmap -layout ua,us,ru -variant winkeys,, -option grp:caps_toggle
```

английский

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ua,ru -variant ,winkeys, -option grp:caps_toggle
```

и так далее. То есть, мы не просто указываем текущий язык (он первый в списке), но и указываем, порядок переключения и кнопку.

Но есть более радикальные способы. Языков оставляем два, а для русского просто делаем composite key - по факту ведь только 4 отличающиеся буквы нужно. То есть, нажимаем просто кнопку - украинская буква, нажимаем к примеру с правым альтом - русская (і=>ы, ї=>ъ и так далее). Почему не наоборот? Это слишком холиварный вопрос.

Comment: Для ясности, словами упомяните какие клавиши, указанным командам соответствуют — я не понял как указать Ctrl+1,2,3 для включения соответствующих раскладок

Comment: Application Shortcut достаточно простое окно. Там все сильно очевидно.

Comment: Я не вижу как это относится к вашему ответу и как он  отвечает на вопрос автора.

Comment: Если у Вас не lubuntu/xfce, то да, ответ неочевилен.

Comment: Я не понимаю каким образом ваши комментарии проясняют работу команд setxkbmap из вашего ответа.

Comment: setxkbmap занимается только переключением. А горячие кнопки отрабатываются Application Shortcut. В своём ответе я привел пример, как найти заведомо рабочие параметры.

Comment: если setxkbmap занимается только переключением (то есть не настраивает, а переключает), то что фраза из ответа *"указываем, порядок переключения и кнопку"* означает? Не ясно из ответа, команда  *задаёт*  порядок переключения или всё таки *включает* нужную раскладку? К примеру, xdotool key super+space *переключает* раскладку на моей машине (сами клавиши в другом месте *задаются*).

Comment: И включает раскладку, и может задать порядок. Я об этом писал.

Comment: если бы ваш ответ был для ясным, я не стал бы спрашивать. Не хотите, не отвечайте

Comment: Я отвечаю. Но кажется, кто то просто меня троллит.

Answer (score 0):

В gnome-shell можно поменять раскладку через JavaScript поверх DBus:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
--object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
--method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
 "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

Смена будет на первую (нулевую) раскладу. Соответственно для любой другой раскладки достаточно указать её порядковый номер.

Затем идём в настройки клавиатуры и добавляем своё сочетание клавиш:

[image]